# Getting .Net Core 2.0 Self-contained to publish framework DLLs

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

The setup:
[image: VS 2017 v 15.3.0]

.Net Core 2.0 Plain MVC template:
[image: Core 2.0 dependencies]

Publishing to a folder:
[image]

I added the RuntimeIdentifiers:
[image]

But I CAN NOT get VS to copy the .Net Core DLLs to the output folder, just the site files.  I've read this: [MS Core Manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-vs) and it seems like it should include them.  "dotnet restore" also seems to do nothing.

WHAT am I missing?!?!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly what the issue was, but it appears the latest VS update just days after the v15.3 is a new v15.3.1 that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you want to go back, now that you can include all in just one .dll

Anyway if that is what you need then change the Microsoft.AspNetCore.All to specific includes.

Change:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0" />
    ...
```

To:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.0.0" />
    ...
```

And restart VS before Publish...

=)